# Java constructor called multiple times?

Tags: java

I built a program in order to test Java inheritance, there are several classes:

```
public class Animal {
    String name = "";
    String kind = "";

    public Animal() {
        System.out.println(desc());
    }

    public Animal(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        System.out.println(desc());
    }


    String desc() {
        if (name == "") {
            return "Je suis un animal.";
        } else {
            return "Je suis un animal de nom " + name + ".";
        }
    }
}




public class Mamifere extends Animal {    
    public Mamifere() {
        System.out.println(desc());
    }

    public Mamifere(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        System.out.println(desc());
    }

    String desc() {
        return super.desc() + " Je suis un mamifère.";
    }    
}

public class Homme extends Mamifere {    
    public Homme() {
        System.out.println(desc());
    }

    public Homme(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        System.out.println(desc());
    }

    String desc() {
        return super.desc() + " Je suis un homme.";
    }    
}

public class Chien extends Mamifere {    
    public Chien() {
        System.out.println(desc());
    }

    public Chien(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        System.out.println(desc());
    }

    String desc() {
        return super.desc() + " Je suis un chien.";
    }    
}
```

When I run this code:

```
public class TestAnimal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal[] animaux = new Animal[5];
        animaux[0] = new Animal("Truc");
        animaux[1] = new Animal();
        animaux[2] = new Chien("Medor");
        animaux[3] = new Homme();
        animaux[4] = new Homme("Robert");

    }

}
```

I get this output:

```
Je suis un animal de nom Truc.
Je suis un animal.
Je suis un animal. Je suis un mamifère. Je suis un chien.
Je suis un animal. Je suis un mamifère. Je suis un chien.
Je suis un animal de nom Medor. Je suis un mamifère. Je suis un chien.
Je suis un animal. Je suis un mamifère. Je suis un homme.
Je suis un animal. Je suis un mamifère. Je suis un homme.
Je suis un animal. Je suis un mamifère. Je suis un homme.
Je suis un animal. Je suis un mamifère. Je suis un homme.
Je suis un animal. Je suis un mamifère. Je suis un homme.
Je suis un animal de nom Robert. Je suis un mamifère. Je suis un homme.
```

Why is there so many repetitions for the objects constructed from the argument less constructor ?

Comment: You seem to have defined `Homme` twice and omitted `Animal` from your question. Please correct this

Comment: @Phil I added the missing class

Comment: You call super desc in everything, why wouldn't they print?

Comment: You have 2 levels of inheritance and are including super prints everywhere along with regular printing statements

Comment: super.super.super..... will of course print everything.

Comment: See also [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: @shmosel Thanks. Java is weird !

Comment: It's also usually preferable to use `null` to indicate "unset", which is different from "a value that is empty".

Comment: @chrylis Thank you! In this case though I am doing a recursive call where I need my string objects to have an actual empty value in order to recursively concatenate them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `Chien` extends `Mammifere` and `Mamifere` extends `Animal` : when you want to instanciate an `Chien` it also builds an `Mamifere` as it's a super-type and so it also builds an `Animal` as it's also a super type

- you're seeing the `desc` method launched by `Chien` constructor
- you're seeing the `desc` method launched by `Mamifere` constructor
- you're seeing the `desc` method launched by `Animal` constructor

The same happens hor `Homme`

Comment: That's interesting. Why does some IDEs (such as Eclipse), generate constructors where an explicit call (`super(args)`) to the superclass constructor is done ? Is there any difference with not calling it ?

Comment: @TrevörAnneDenise when you need to call super-constructor with parameter it's required to use super(arg1, arg2, ..) but for no-param it's good practice bu it' would work without

Comment: @TrevörAnneDenise as String are object, this is not a suprising behavior ;)